# Food flickering and not being eaten in dodge game

Tags: java, stddraw

[old code](https://repl.it/C2Da)

Currently, I am trying to make a game in which the mouse controls a block that will move around, gathering little balls. Every time a ball spawns, an enemy will appear, moving in a linear path.

My program attempts to implement that, however the enemies all spawn at once and are moving right only. The food, when eaten, does not disappear. Instead, when I move the mouse, the food flickers all over the place and the enemy moves all towards the right side. I'm not sure how to make the food appear once and stay there, then when the player eats it, it disappears and spawns another one somewher else, and spawns an enemy as well that moves in left-right or up-down and bounces off the walls.

I would like to make the food spawn in one place, then when I eat it, delete the food and spawn another one randomly.

I am trying to [make something similar to this.](http://beedigital.net/coolgames/the-dodge-game/)

Thanks for your help.

EDIT: New code based off of the psuedocode in @AJC's answer

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class Game{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        StdDraw.setXscale(0,100);
        StdDraw.setYscale(0,100);

        int foodX = 0;
        int foodY = 0;

        ArrayList enemyXPos = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList enemyYPos = new ArrayList();
        ArrayList enemySpeeds = new ArrayList();
        int score = 0;
        Random rand = new Random();

        while (true) {
            double playerX = StdDraw.mouseX();
            double playerY = StdDraw.mouseY();
            StdDraw.clear();

            int enemyX = 0, enemyY = 0;


            if (playerX == foodX && playerY == foodY) {
                score += 1;

                foodX = rand.nextInt(100);
                foodY = rand.nextInt(100);


                enemyX = rand.nextInt(100);
                enemyY = rand.nextInt(100);

                enemyXPos.add(enemyX);
                enemyYPos.add(enemyY);
                int enemySpeed = rand.nextInt(20);
                enemySpeeds.add(enemySpeed);
            }

            for (int j = 0; j < enemyXPos.size()-1; j++) {
                if ((int) enemyXPos.get(j) == playerX && (int) enemyYPos.get(j) == playerY) {
                    break;
                }

            }
            for (int j = 0; j < enemyXPos.size()-1; j++) {
                enemyXPos.add(j, (int) enemyXPos.get(j) + (int) enemySpeeds.get(j));
                enemyYPos.add(j, (int) enemyXPos.get(j) + (int) enemySpeeds.get(j));
            }


            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.BLUE);
            StdDraw.filledCircle(playerX, playerY, 5);

            StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.GREEN);
            StdDraw.filledCircle(foodX, foodY, 2);

            for (int j = 0; j < enemyXPos.size()-1; j++) {
                StdDraw.setPenColor(StdDraw.RED);
                StdDraw.filledCircle(enemyX, enemyY, 2);
            }
            StdDraw.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it is very difficult to determine what represents each of those three things in your code (the food, the block and the enemies).

Comment: Have a look at `ArrayList` and how it could help you having more than one individual enemy. Think about "the player eating the food" as an event; there's a way to detect this event, only then should you re-position the food. As it stands your code is not much of an attempt and your question is too broad to answer straight: like randomising a position and direction for your enemies is a whole different problem that you should find plenty of answers to already.

Comment: @Beyeler i'll take a look around and see what I can find.

Comment: I've never used `StdDraw`, but if it is the Princeton Intro to CS provided class here http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/javadoc/StdDraw.html, I'd suggest reading the `show` method documentation to handle the flickering.

Comment: @Chill I have a feeling the flicker is the result of me showing then clearing the screen infinitely

Comment: Player and enemies should have their own classes. Enemy positions and  speed belongs to enemy not the Game. You create enemy instances in your Game class and store those in ArraList.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code

1. You are setting the food to a random position every game loop, so it will not stay in one place. You need to remember the position of the current food, and set a new position **only** when the player touches it
2. The enemies are controlled all by one variable, so they will all move in the same direction obviously
3. There are some other logic flaws, like the updates for the other objects get skipped when the player doesn't move
4. I also suggest organizing the code into sections, like separating the draw and update cycles

New pseudocode:

```
Variables:
 - Current food position
 - List of enemy positions
 - List of enemy velocities

Game loop:
    //Update stuff
    Get mouse location
    Set player location to mouse location

    If player is touching food then
        Increase score
        Set food position to random position
        Spawn new enemy:
            Add new random position to enemy position list
            Add new random velocity to enemy velocity list
    End if

    For each enemy:
        If enemy is touching player than
            End game
        End if
    End for

    For each enemy:
        Update enemy location:
            Add velocity of enemy to position of enemy
            (posX=posX+velX)
            (posY=posY+velY)
    End for

    //Draw stuff
    Draw player
    Draw food
    For each enemy:
        Draw that enemy
    End for
End game loop
```

Comment: I've made another copy based off of this. This time, however, the food refuses to delete itself after I hit it. See the edit

Comment: Are you sure your collision checking is correct? For your new code to work, the player and food have to be at exactly on the same pixel. A crude, but better collision detection would be to check if the distance between the center of the square and the center of the player is less than the radius of the player circle.

Comment: @RegisteredUser Are you sure your collision checking is correct? For your new code to work, the player and food have to be at exactly on the same pixel. A crude, but better collision detection would be to check if the distance between the center of the square and the center of the player is less than the radius of the player circle.